# Interpreting different outputs from beta regression

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, logit, beta-distribution, beta-regression

I have the following data structure:

```
Percent-"yes"    Average-score    Region
70%              0.03             A
66%              0.07             B
57%              0.09             C
85%              0.06             D
.... etc
```

I have aggregated data by regions. The outcome variable is Percent-"yes" (indicating the percent of people answering "yes" for a survey question) and explanatory variable is Average-score (indicating the average of a score by all the people in that region).

The statistical model used is beta regression using logit link function. The beta-coefficient for Average-score is 0.06.

I interpret it as "*For 1 unit increase in Average-score, there is a **0.06 units increase** in log-odds of **Percent-"yes"***". A colleague told me the 2 bolded elements in the statement are wrong, I have a tough time figuring out why that is the case despite exhausting all my reference material. Any insights or material I can check out to figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your interpretation is correct - not sure why your colleague indicated that this is wrong. Unless I'm overlooking something, the only caveat in the interpretation is that this does not necessarily correspond to individual probabilities/odds due to the averaging within the region.

Another useful approach to interpreting the output of betareg is to set up a new data frame with values of the regressor(s) that are "of interest" and then `predict()` the desired quantities, e.g., the expectation, variance, quantiles etc. And then you can graph these or present them in a table.

For a worked example of this approach see Figure 2 in `vignette("betareg", package = "betareg")` that shows the fitted mean of the response for varying the main regressor and keeping the other regressor fixed at a "typical" level. The constructed data frame with the values "of interest" is simply: `data.frame(temp = 150:500, batch = "6")`. See code chunk number 5 in `edit(vignette(...))` for the exact replication code.

Comment: I was hinted that my "0.06 units increase" being wrong has something to do with the unit of the regressor. The individual level Score is from 0-100%. When I aggregate it, I think it should still range from 0-100%. I still can't see how this plays a role in interpreting the change in log odds.

Comment: When the coefficient is to be interpreted as "1 unit change in regressor", does it mean it changes from 0 to 1? So in my case it changes from 0% to 100%? And if I want to define how much log odds it changes the outcome by "1% change in the regressor", does it mean I need to divide the beta-coefficient by 100?

Comment: The regression equation for the expectation of your response `mu = E(percent_yes)` is `logit(mu) = a + b * average_score` then a 1-unit increase in `average_score` leads to an increase of `b` units in `logit(mu)`. So far this is hopefully obvious. The question is whether `logit(mu)` are the _log-odds_ of `percent_yes`. I think it is ok to say this but one can argue that it is a bit sloppy. Because `mu` is not the individual probability to choose "yes" but an average frequency over a population. But I guess it depends on your application whether it is ok/useful to say so or not.